# Selected list item gets de-selected as I select others

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, ribbon

I am having issues with my Ribbon Tools when selecting list items. I am using the [SharePoint Hillbilly Tabs](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOzI7IpovUAhUN8YMKHU3QCNMQFggkMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.markrackley.net%2F2015%2F08%2F16%2Fsharepoint-tabbed-web-partshillbillytabs-3-0%2F&usg=AFQjCNHFPr42Wvv-0lCSobt5mGleTca1sg&sig2=DLrr7qPOlXZl_bnT2UAp8A) in SharePoint 2016.

When I select 1 item the tools show up, but if I select the 2nd item, the first item disappears and the tabs disappear.

Right now I can't select more than two items before they disappear
[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking a 3rd party tool... contact Mark at support@PAITGroup.com